# How can I run gdb in xemacs for cross-compiled code?

Tags: linux, emacs, gdb, cross-platform, xemacs

I don't use emacs, but I know xemacs can be used as a front-end for gdb (used it before).  However, my code is cross-compiled, so I can't run gdb, I have to run a specific version of gdb that's for the cross-compiled code (let's call it gdb-foo).  How do I set xemacs up to run the alternate gdb?

When I use `M-x, gdb` I get the prompt:

`Run gdb on file:`

I remember seeing something like this:

`Run gdb like this:`

But I don't know how to get that.

Next, once I learn how to do it this way, how can I do it as a one-liner I can run from bash, including gdb-foo and attach options?  (I know bash scripting; I just need the incantation for xemacs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to change gdb executable. Let's see how to retrieve this kind of information using emacs.

Under emacs, you can do `C-h f gdb` to print gdb function help:

```
gdb is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
‘gdb-mi.el’.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <tools> <gdb>.... etc.
```

Then click on `gdb-mi.el` to go to the lisp source. From there you can search for "executable" (`C-s executable`, then `C-s` for next occurrence). You will find this customizable variable:

```
(defcustom gud-gdb-command-name "gdb -i=mi"
  "Default command to execute an executable under the GDB debugger."
  :type 'string
  :group 'gdb)
```

And that's it! You have all the information you need.

Now to effectively change `gdb` to `gdb-foo`, run the customize command: `M-x customize`. Then type "gud-gdb-command-name" in the search field + return. You should get something like:

```
gud-gdb-command-name                              Search 

Operate on all settings in this buffer:
 Revert...   Apply   Apply and Save 

Hide Gud Gdb Command Name: gdb -i=mi      <---- MODIFY ME!
    State : STANDARD.
   Default command to execute an executable under the GDB debugger.
Groups: Gdb
```

You can modify `"gdb -i=mi"` to `"gdb-foo -i=mi"` then "Apply" or "Apply and Save".

Comment: Thanks! but I get `\`gdb' is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function
  -- autoloads from "gdb"` and clicking on `gdb` does nothing; double-clicking it just sets a mark.  I'm running `XEmacs 21.4 (patch 22) "Instant Classic" [Lucid] (x86_64-linux-gnu, Mule) of Mon Nov  4 2013 on toyol`

Comment: And jumping directly to "M-x customize", then "gud-gdb-command-name " in the search field? (my idea was to describe all the steps I used to get the solution I proposed)

Comment: However, you only have to customize the "gud-gdb-command-name" variable (at least with my Emacs version 25.5, not sure if my proposal is still ok with your version)

Comment: I've been busy with other things.  I originally tried what  you suggest and it led nowhere, but I need to post back with specifics.  I believe it's a version difference issue, plus general emacs ignorance on my part.

Comment: I hope I am not orientating you in a wrong direction, however I think it is the right way (customization of the `gud-gdb-command-name` variable). Thanks for the feedback.